# Running a query in Data Explorer returns a JSON string {"captcha":true}

Tags: bug, data-explorer, captcha

I am trying to run this query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/430132/split-users-by-amount-of-reputation-digits

When I hit <kbd>Run Query</kbd>, it redirects to a page with nothing but a JSON string:

```
{"captcha":true}
```

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the page:

[image]

Comment: Can you clear cookies etc.? I recognize that message from wanting to run a SEDE query programmatically without being logged in.

Comment: Are you sure you allow third-party cookies and have not blocked Google domains? Which browser are you using, on which OS? Any adblockers /  other userscripts that might interfer giving you a re-captcha. If you go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/captcha) do you get a captcha?

Comment: Possibly related (includes domains for JavaScript code): *[Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)*

Comment: No repro even if I'm not logged in. I do get a captcha and clicking the  box allows me to run the query.

Comment: @rene I block all third-party cookies, and it still runs okay.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue on Windows 10 + Chrome Version 105.0.5195.102. One way to circumvent the issue that worked for me was opening an incognito window  in Chrome and run the SEDE query there.