# What's going on with SEDE right now? It's being fickle

Tags: support, data-explorer

When I open a new tab, I get "we are currently offline", and then I refresh a couple of times and it's fine.

Then when I try to run a query, it will give

> unknown job being polled!

or

> Something unexpected went wrong while running your query. Don't worry, blame is already being assigned.

But sometimes the query will go through.

What's going on?

I'm using SEDE as an "anonymous" user.

Also weird is that

- I can log in, but then when I try to compose a query, the first time, it gave me the anonymous user page, and then on subsequent attempts, I was recognized as logged-in, but in the browser console, I saw errors when clicking the run button like "`Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined`" (why is captcha-related code being run if I'm logged in?).
- Attempts to run a query again will take at least a second, but the response will still claim that it ran in under a second, and that the response was cached.

Comment: The last exception I see from the OpServer side for SEDE is on December 13th, and I've taken a few swings at things with no ill effects, so not sure what is happening to you...

Comment: I can reproduce SEDE issues. Trying to run [a random query](https://data.stackexchange.com/query/run/1/466/466) anonymously yields `{"captcha":true}` (a page containing just that). I'm also experiencing slow loading times on pages. Trying to log in gives [this](https://i.imgur.com/lJwik3h.jpg). I get a slightly-better, but still incomplete page with my userscripts and adblocker disabled. Refreshing a few times did get the login page eventually, though. /cc @AaronBertrand

Comment: What @cocomac sees has been reported before https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354414/running-a-query-in-data-explorer-returns-a-json-string-captchatrue  but I hardly ever manage reproduce that.  I can't repro here what the OP experieces.

Comment: It seems client side network speed related. If I put Chrome on a throttle for 3G speed clicking the  "Run Query" button returns me JSON instead of a rendered page. I've jet to encounter a server-side error but at least this gives me enough clues to get the JSON stuff fixed.

Comment: @rene that could be it... I was/am doing some stuff that's doing about 100ish KiB/s downstream and upstream. But now SEDE seems okay.

Comment: @rene I don't think it's speed-related. I'm currently on a network with 400Mbps up and down and am encountering the same issue. Looking at the actual requests being sent, there's some weird behavior going on. After a handful of sub-second poll requests, the requests start taking multiple seconds each, and after about 4 or 5 I get "unknown job being polled". I've also randomly gotten the `{"captcha":true}` response while being logged in, which seems wrong. I've also gotten "A severe error occurred on the current command" a couple of times. The site, in general, is also just super slow.

Comment: I'm seeing sluggishness now, but it's quite possible we've "meta effect"ed ourselves. It's still only a couple of web servers in front of a database so if everyone here is piling on, on top of who knows what kind of scraping and other stuff is happening...

Comment: I've definitely spotted high volumes of nefarious scraping-like activity from a handful of bots today, and will be working with SRE to tap some kneecaps. Not sure if it's related to the symptoms you've shared but I will resolve the current issue and then dig into similarities.

Comment: @AaronBertrand scraping as in actually running queries? for my curiosity, could you point to the datestamp under "queries -> everything" where those queries start being requested?

Comment: @starball Some queries, yes, and a lot of other types of requests. I can't really disclose details, and precise timestamps are very cumbersome to pinpoint since the type of activity we're concerned about is usually ramped up very slowly. But I can tell exactly when one of the rule changes [shut a huge portion of traffic down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXV0V.png). :-)